# read csv file from user input in django

Tags: python, django, django-views

ERROR :

**FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/media/tableConvert.com_v02pvt.csv'**

Hello there im trying to read a csv file in django backend where user upload and i dont want to save it to my DB so my best try was this :

**View :**

```
def view_submit_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        text = request.POST.get('smstext')
        csv_file = request.FILES['csv_file']
        file_name = default_storage.save(csv_file.name, csv_file)
        file_url = default_storage.url(file_name)
        df = pd.read_csv(r'{}'.format(file_url))

    return render(request, 'SubmitForm/form.html',)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read it from the request itself without saving it.
Using ".file" command you can fetch the readable state of the file.

```
def view_submit_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        text = request.POST.get('smstext')
        csv_file = request.FILES.get('csv_file')
        df = pd.read_csv(csv_file.file)
    return render(request, 'SubmitForm/form.html',)
```

[Shell command as image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iR9XR.png)